# SQL: how to get sunday of current week

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

I want to get the last day( Sunday) of current week given any timestamp. I tried following script, but it returns Saturday as the last day rather than Sunday as I expected.

```
Select DATEADD(DAY , 7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()),GETDATE()) AS 'Last Day Of Week'
```

Any answer is welcomed!!

Comment: So you want week to be Monday -> Sunday? Default in SQL Server is Sunday -> Saturday.

Comment: Also refer this
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2009/06/17/How-to-get-the-Nth-weekday-of-a-month.aspx

Comment: Saturday is day 7, weeks start in sundays.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It will work if you change the standard DATEFIRST from Sunday (7) to Monday (1):

```
SET DATEFIRST 1

Select DATEADD(DAY , 7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()),GETDATE()) AS 'Last Day Of Week'
```

Answer (score 3):

```sql
DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 6)
```

I know this post is old but this post comes at the top when searched through via Google.

Always good to be updating.

Answer (score 1):

The below doesn't work on a sunday with some `DATEFIRST` (languages):

```sql
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 6)
```

Also, setting `DATEFIRST` is not always an option (functions can't use `SET DATEFIRST`)

Here's one that's universal:

- It's geared for weeks starting on a Monday
- Always returns the Sunday of the current week
- Works regardless of the `DATEFIRST` setting
- Does not change `DATEFIRST` so can be used in a function

```sql
    DECLARE @today DATE = getdate(); (or any other date);

    SELECT dateadd(day, ((15-@@datefirst) - datepart(dw, @today)) % 7, @today);
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefix your command with `set datefirst 1`